# Basic proof that Isogeny = group homomorphism without Riemann Roch?

Tags: alternative-proof, elliptic-curves, group-homomorphism

It is a well known fact that an isogeny $f:E_1\rightarrow E_2$ between elliptic curves (i.e., where $f(O)=O$) is a group homomorphism under the natural group structure of the elliptic curves.

Every proof that I have found (usually based on Silverman's book) uses  Riemann-Roch theorem. Of course, it is a very important theorem, so why not.

But I was wondering if it is possible to prove it directly, without first going to $\operatorname{Pic}^0(E_i)$. Does anyone know of any such proof? (The simple the better, of course).

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is proven for abelian varieties (of any dimension, the 1-dimensional case being elliptic curves) as Corollary 1 in section 4 of Mumford's *Abelian Varieties*. It is an immediate corollary of the "rigidity lemma" stated immediately prior:

> **Rigidity Lemma (Form I).** Let $X$ be a complete variety, $Y$ and $Z$ any varieties, and $f\colon X \times Y \to Z$ a morphism such that for some $y_0 \in Y$, $f(X \times \{y_0\})$ is a single point $z_0$ of $Z$. Then there is a morphism $g\colon Y \to Z$ such that if $p_2\colon X \times Y \to Y$ is the projection, $f = g \circ p_2$.

In other words, if $f$ is constant on *one* fiber of the projection map $p_2$, then $f$ is constant on *every* fiber of $p_2$.

The proof is brief, so I'll just reproduce it here:

> *Proof.* Choose any point $x_0 \in X$, and deﬁne $g\colon Y \to Z$ by $g(y) = f(x_0, y)$. Since $X \times Y$ is a variety, to show that $f = g \circ p_2$, it is sufficient to show that these morphisms coincide on some open subset of $X \times Y$. Let $U$ be an affine open neighbourhood of $z_0$ in $Z$, $F = Z - U$, and $G = p_2(f^{-1}(F))$; then $G$ is closed in $Y$ since $X$ is complete and hence $p_2$ is a closed map. Further $y_0 \notin G$ since $f(X \times \{y_0\}) = \{z_0\}$. Therefore $Y - G = V$ is a non-empty open subset of $Y$. For each $y \in V$, the complete variety $X \times \{y\}$ gets mapped by $f$ into the affine variety $U$, and hence to a single point of $U$. But this means that for
> any $x \in X$, $y \in V$, $f(x, y) = f(x_0, y) = g \circ p_2(x, y)$, and this proves
> our assertion.

In particular, if $f \colon X \to Y$ is a morphism of abelian varieties such that $f(0_X) = 0_Y$, then the morphism $\phi\colon X \times X \to Y$ defined for all $x_1, x_2 \in X$ by
$$\phi(x_1, x_2) = f(x_1 + x_2) - f(x_1) - f(x_2)$$
is constant with value $0_Y$ on $X \times \{0_X\}$ and $\{0_X\} \times X$. Applying the rigidity lemma, $\phi$ is constant everywhere on $X \times X$, which means that $f$ is a homomorphism.

The analogous relative statement for abelian schemes (over any base scheme) is Corollary 6.4 in Mumford, Fogarty, and Kirwan's *Geometric Invariant Theory*. The general idea of that proof is similar.

References:

- Mumford, D. *Abelian Varieties*. Corrected reprint of the second (1974) edition. Tata Institute of Fundamental Research Studies in Mathematics, vol. 5. Hindustan Book Agency, New Delhi, 2008. ISBN: 978-81-85931-86-9. [[MR 2514037](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2514037)]
- Mumford, D., Fogarty, J., and Kirwan, F. *Geometric Invariant Theory*. Third edition. Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete, vol. 34. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1994. ISBN: 3-540-56963-4. [[MR 1304906](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1304906)]

Comment: There is also a GTM book by Hindry and Silverman, which should contain a (presumably the same) proof.

Comment: You're right, this is Lemma A.7.1.1 and Corollary A.7.1.2 in Hindry and Silverman's book, and they give essentially the same proof.

Comment: Thank you guys very much. I will have a look at it, but it certainly seems to be on the right  track. Cheers.